# Cannot delete data in other table linked with foreign key in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two table one is for role and other for its permission i want to delete role permission when i delete role. For that i have linked role table with role permission with the help of below code in migration, but it is not deleting data from role permission.

```
class Role extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
         Schema::create('role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreign('id')->references('role_id')->on('role_permission')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

> Role Permission :

```
class CreateRolePermission extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_permission', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('role_id');
            $table->integer('module_id');
            $table->integer('permission');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You put the foreign constraints in the wrong order.

It should be the `role_permission` references to the `role` by `id` through `role_id`, like this:

```php
// inside CreateRolePermission 
$table->foreign('role_id')
  ->references('id')
  ->on('role')
  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Also, delete the `foreign` in the `role` table

Comment: I tried it but the data from role permission are not deleted when i delete role

Comment: Did you try it after rerun migrations?

Comment: Yes i rerun migrations

Comment: In rolepermission table i can see the following created indexes :role_permission_role_id_foreign BTREE No No role_id  A No

Answer (score 1):

I think you have created foreign key in wrong table

just remove

```
$table->foreign('id')->references('role_id')->on('role_permission')->onDelete('cascade');
```

from role migration and add

```
$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('role')->onDelete('cascade');
```

in role_permission migration

Comment: I tried it but the data from role permission are not deleted when i delete role

Comment: In role table id is big integr and in role permission its integer so change $table->integer('role_id'); to $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id'); in role permission migration

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from role migration

$table->foreign('id')->references('role_id')->on('role_permission')->onDelete('cascade');

and add it inside in CreateRolePermission like this

class CreateRolePermission extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_permission', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('role_id');
            $table->integer('module_id');
            $table->integer('permission');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('role')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }